# CSS: Aligning a word in a div with a line in an adjacent one

Tags: css

I am trying to align a word with a line, each in a separate div.

The code is below. The attached image illustrates the desired result.

[image]

1. I'd like it to work on Chrome, Firefox and IE (including older versions - IE8, etc.).
2. There should be a space between the left border of the container and the word "Daily".
3. The dotted line should extend the entire width of the "line div" to the border of the "container".
4. There should be a space between the word "Daily" and the beginning of the line

I cannot get it to work.  In Firefox, for example, the word "Daily" is aligned to the left border of the container. And the line is not aligned, it's displayed below the intended position.

Please help!

CODE

```css
container {
  position: relative;
  width: 565px;
  float: left;
}

.daily {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 85%;
  top: 0px;
  border-bottom: dotted black 2px;
}

html>body .line {
  top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="daily">Daily</div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no attached image

Comment: why don't you just use diplsay flez and align items center?

Comment: "I'd like it to work on Chrome, Firefox and IE (including older versions - IE8, etc.)." How far back do you want to go? [IE8 has not been supported on any Windows platform for many years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8). What about Netscape Navigator? Do you need answers to support that too?

Comment: The image is displayed in the body of the post.  I didn't lnow how to attach it, sorry.  Some users are stil on IE8 (XP) - not many.  Most use IE11.  I only need CSS to work on Chrome, FF and IE8 and above.  No other browsers.  Flex work on IE11, not IE8.  Netscape!! -:)

Comment: Is there a way in CSS to control the  "Vertical Alignment" of the word "Daily".  Since the dotted line is the bottom border of the right div, perhaps if one could make the word "Daily" touch the lower border of the left div - something like:-
vertical-alignment: bottom;

Answer (score 0):

Use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) and align items to the text baseline:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  font-size:2em;
  border:1px solid red;
  padding: 10px 0;/* vertical padding */
}

.daily {
  margin-left: 20px; /* The space between the left border of the container and the text. */
  margin-right: .5ch; /* The space between the text and line. Here set to half a character width. */
}

.line {
  flex-grow: 1; /* fill the remaining space */
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #bbb;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="daily">Daily</div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

> I'd like it to work on Chrome, Firefox and IE (including older versions - IE8, etc.).

At the time of writing [Flexbox has 98.3% global support](https://caniuse.com/flexbox) and is very widely used. All major browsers (including Chrome, Firefox and Edge) support it. Even IE10 can do it (with a browser prefix) but sadly no support on IE8 - which ended life on January 12, 2016.

> There should be a space between the left border of the container and the word "Daily".

`.daily {margin-left: 20px;}`

> The dotted line should extend the entire width of the "line div" to the border of the "container".

`.line {flex-grow: 1;}`

> There should be a space between the word "Daily" and the beginning of the line

`.daily {margin-right: .5ch;}`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your responses. I am still learning CSS and have found them very useful.  For this particular task, I needed a code that works on Chrome, Firefox and IE8 and above.

I believe the following simple code does the job.

Best regards!

CODE

```
.wrapper-daily-headline {
    top:20px;
    position:relative;
    width: 565px;
    float:left;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.Table{
    width:565px;
}
.Table td.line {
    width:514px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    padding:7 0 0 0;
}
.Table td.daily{
    vertical-align:top;
    width:40px;
    padding: 0 0 0 15;
}
.hr_daily_line
{
    border-top:  dotted black 2px;
    padding:0 0 0 2;
}

<div class="wrapper-daily-headline">
<table class="Table">
  <tr>
    <td class="daily">Daily</td>
    <td class="line"><hr class="hr_daily_line"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use display:flex and align-items:center. See below code.

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5px;
}

.line {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <p>Text
  </p>
  <span class="line"></span>
</div>
```